# Error, blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, html, app

He tenido el siguiente error o problema:

> Access to script at 'file:///C:/User/Perfil/Document/cross/app/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comparto el codigo:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Error CROSS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main id="app"></main>
  <script src="app/index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*index.js*

```
import { App } from "./App.js";

const d = document;

d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", App);
```

*App.js*

```
export function App() {
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `<h1>Bienvenido a mi App</h1>`;
}
```

La estrucutra de mi proyecto:

```
 /cross
  /app
    App.js
    index.js
  index.html
```

Utilizo un servidor local (Apache) y como se puede observar no tengo ninguna solicitud a ningun servidor o API externa. Solo es cargar contenido en un html.

Comment: Estas tratando de hacer una peticion por `ajax` o simplemente una peticion y no haz puesto el codigo??, porque normalmente eso pasa es con peticiones externas, y no con simples imports.

Comment: Pareciera que abriste el index.html haciendo doble click, porque te está sirviendo `file:///C:/User/Perfil/Document/cross/index.html`

Comment: Pense que se trataria de que no estas corriendo el proyecto en un servidor local, pero al parecer si lo haces, ademas el error es de `CORS`, asi que esta aun mas rara la cosa

Comment: @Riven, estabas en lo correcto, el mensaje de error contiene la ruta `file:///C:/User/Perfil/Document/cross/app/index.js`

Comment: @Triby, aun asi el error se presenta por algo totalmente distinto (cors), no creo que los modulos hagan un `Cross Origin Request`, o si?, de ser asi, el error simplemente es a que el usuario abrio el archivo sin mas xd

Comment: @Riven, el error es claro: No está ejecutando el script desde un servidor o está tratando de acceder a un recurso por ruta en disco. En cualquier caso, está usando el protocolo `file:///`. Seguramente abrió `index.html` desde el explorador de archivos.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912641/access-to-script-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-error-whil

Aqui preguntaron lo mismo que tu y dice que no puedes usar el archivo script como modulo sin un servidor.
Y lo que te dicen es que instales un extension en Visual Studio Code que se live server y le das click derecho y abrir con Live Server tu archivo index.html